# What plant will grow from these seeds?

Tags: identification, seedlings

Last month, I found in my kitchen a bag of chia seeds intended for human consumption, but the expiration date was in 2017. Instead of throwing them away, I sprinkled some in several cells of my seedling tray, and, guess what, some started growing. I have no idea about the plant that these chia seeds originate from though. Can you help me find some info on what plant could grow from these seeds. I only know (from the label) that the origin country of the seeds is Bolivia.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Chia usually refers to Salvia hispanica, an annual  herb plant https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salvia_hispanica

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nice experiment. I think if your seeds still germinate they are still okay for consumption (but that is my opinion, no guarantees).

One way to use these plants, is to eat the sprouts, just like with bean sprouts (very nutritious). You can also make tea from leaves of older plants.

I found a web site [here](https://dengarden.com/gardening/How-I-grow-and-harvest-organic-Chia), about growing chia yourself.

Comment: Need a statue of Bob Ross to grow seeds on: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=bon+ross+chia&t=ffsb&iax=images&ia=images